# How can I see my balance?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, balance, connection, issue

I'm just new to Monero and downloaded the wallet a couple of days ago. It was fully synced and I've sent 3 transactions to the wallet. Everything was working fine. I synced through a remote node. Today I wanted to send some XMR to an exchange, just to try. It did not work it said unable to connect to the daemon. Although my wallet said it was connected. Then I closed the Gui and restarted.

I only see the first of the three transactions shown in the wallet. When I start the monerod.exe, it says it's fully synced.

So now I've restarted my computer and the wallet shows my whole balance again, but I'm still unable to send monero. Although I have synced after a while and the GUI says it is unable to send because of no connection to the daemon.

I've sent a test amount to an exchange it worked, but now my balance shows only half is spendable. Although I've already confirmed that before!

Now all of my balance is validated and it seems running fine, but just one quick question: is this normal or am I just doing something wrong?

What do you think of this?

Would be awesome if someone could help me out.

Thanks so much!